# Top 2 most common elements inside array in Python

Tags: python

I got this interview problem from leetcode for top k frequent elements, https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/description/ But I decide to simplify the problem just most common elements to make it simpler to solve.  If the 3 item has the same frequentcy, then it's okay to return all 3.

```
"""Given an array, return an array of the top 2 most elements. // Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4] | Output: [3, 4] // Input: [2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4] | Output: [2,4]"""   

import collections

def top2Frequent(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type k: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    if len(nums) < 2:
        return []
    freq = {}
    for num in nums:
        if num in freq:
            freq[num] = freq[num] + 1
        else:
            freq[num] = 1

    bucket = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for key in freq:
        f = freq[key]
        bucket[f].append(key)
    res = []
    count = len(nums)  # the upper limit for res
    while len(res) < 2:
        if bucket[count]:
            res += bucket[count]
        count -= 1
    return res


nums = [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4]  # [4,3]
solution = top2Frequent(nums)
print(solution) # [4,3]
```

https://gist.github.com/Jeffchiucp/2e733e57476bd697bc430cdf48f6e180

I am also tried to solve this problem without using any python library built in collections.

Comment: I'm confused, you say you don't want to use the built-in collections, but you used `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: I don't think the code works as required, when I use `nums = [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]` the result is `[3, 2, 4]`. Please fix this before people can answer the question, see also["If your question contains broken code…"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3650#3650).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're okay with using the built-in collections module, I'd suggest the following. `collections.Counter` is ideally suited for this and will make the problem trivial.

```
from collections import Counter


def top_k(numbers, k=2):
    """The counter.most_common([k]) method works
    in the following way:
    >>> Counter('abracadabra').most_common(3)  
    [('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2)]
    """

    c = Counter(numbers)
    most_common = [key for key, val in c.most_common(k)]

    return most_common
```

Without using the built-in collections module, the following will work:

```
def top_k_nobuiltin(numbers, k=2):
    # The first part is identical to your implementation and works just
    # fine
    counter = {}
    for number in numbers:
        if number in counter:
            counter[number] += 1
        else:
            counter[number] = 1

    # The line below creates an iterator that will generate the
    # sequence [(4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 1), (1, 1)], i.e.
    # count the occurrence for each value.
    # In particular, sorted() with key=lambda kv: kv[1] will turn
    # a dictionary into a list of tuples, sorted by the second item
    # of each tuple

    sorted_by_value = reversed(sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]))

    top_vals = [item[0] for item in sorted_by_value][:k]

    return top_vals
```

For both cases, you'll get the desired result:

```
def main():
    nums = [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4]  # [4,3]

    print(top_k(nums))  # [4,3]
    print(top_k_nobuiltin(nums))  # [4,3]    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.

Comment: @TobySpeight I think that the justification for this answer was [self-evident](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7018/9357).

Comment: I think this solutions violate the *must be better than O(n log n)* time complexity requirement.

Comment: I totally agree, hadn't read the leetcode description behind the link. Great answer @RandomDude !

Answer (score 4):

According to the leetcode description one requirement of the algorithm is:

*...must be better than O(n log n), where n is the array's size.*

I am not 100% sure but i think you can't use the built-in `sorted` method of python since it has a time complexity of O(n log n). One possibility for this problem is a bucket sort approach.

The idea:

1. Count frequency of elements in list.
2. Create a list of buckets with `len(nums) + 1` length
3. Iterate over the frequency `dict` and put elements in buckets according to their frequency
4. Iterate in reversed order over the bucket list and return `k` first elements.

```
def top_k_frequent(nums, k):
    cnt = {}
    for n in nums:
        cnt[n] = cnt.get(n, 0) + 1

    bucket = [[] for _ in range(len(nums)+1)]    
    for key, val in cnt.items():
        bucket[val].append(key)

    res = []
    for i in reversed(range(len(bucket))):
        if bucket[i]:
            res.extend(bucket[i])
        if len(res) >= k:
            break

    return res[:k]
```

*Please also see the more elegant approach to count with `dict` in python.*